# Can't get form to work

Tags: php, html, forms

I've searched through the forums and found a lot of threads on this topic but can't seem to find the correct answer or solution for my problem.

I've got a contact form which I can't seem to get working.

HTML:

```
<form action="php/index.php" id="contact-form" method="post" name="form">
<div>
 <label>
 <span>Naam: (verplicht)</span>
 <input name="vname" placeholder="Uw naam" type="text" tabindex="1" required>
 </label>
</div>
<div>
 <label>
 <span>Email: (verplicht)</span>
 <input name="vemail"  placeholder="Uw e-mail adres" type="email" tabindex="2" required>
</label>
</div>
<div>
<label>
<span>Telefoon:</span>
<input name="vphone" placeholder="Telefoon nummer" type="tel" tabindex="3">
</label>
</div>
<div>
<label>
<span>Bericht: (verplicht)</span>
<textarea name="msg" placeholder="Uw vraag of opmerking" tabindex="4" required></textarea>
</label>
</div>
<div>
<input id="send" name="submit" type="submit" value="VERZENDEN">
</div>
</form>
<!-- /Form -->
```

And here is the PHP code, I replaced my e-mail adress in the form with MY EMAIL for obvious reasons.

```
 <?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['vname']; 
    $remark = $_POST['msg']; 
    $from_add = $_POST['vemail']; 
    $to_add = "MY EMAIL"; 
    $subject = "Your Subject Name";
    $phone = $_POST['vphone'];
    $headers = 'From: $from_add';

    if ($phone != null){
        $message = "Naam:$name \n Opmerking: $remark \n mijn telefoon nummer is $phone";
        mail($to_add,$subject,$message,$headers);
    }else{
        $message = "Naam:$name \n Opmerking: $remark";
        mail($to_add,$subject,$message,$headers);
    }   
}
?>
```

Ow I am using XAMPP to run a localhost, perhaps that could be the problem but I'm not sure.

Comment: Is there any error or something? What is the thing that is not working?

Comment: if you want to send email from xamp you should configure SMTP on xamp http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost see this question

Comment: u want to send email from xamp ?

Comment: Well there is no error at all, that is the strangest thing. No warning in my console or nothing, just an empty page and nothing in my inbox.

And no I do not want to use XAMPP to send the e-mail, I am just using XAMPP to get my website to act like it's online.

Comment: I recommend googleing "xampp sendmail gmail" and send emails via gmai.

Comment: @GeertKamps Have you enabled error reporting in php.ini?

Answer (score 0):

I had that same problem with a horrible server which doesn't send emails.

So I used a code that connects to a gmail account and sends the email from there.

try this tutorial: 
http://coded-words.tumblr.com/post/6936532107/configure-gmail-as-smtp-in-xampp-to-send-mail

Edit 23.12.2014:

**Do you have something like this in your code?**

```
 <?php

    $message = "The mail message was sent with the following mail";
    $headers = "From: youremail@gmail.com";
    mail("youremail@gmail.com", "Testing", $message, $headers);

?>
```

(source: http://jiansenlu.blogspot.co.il/2014/10/php-mail-function-using-gmail-account.html)

If you do have this code:

Try submitting a different email address than the one you used in your code. 
Sometimes it goes to the "Sent mail" in your Gmail account without actually showing you that you received a new email. (So you can check your "Sent mail" to see if there is anything over there).

Comment: Well at this point I am more curious if there is something wrong with my code or if there is something wrong with my XAMPP settings. Because I have no idea either way.

Comment: Did you try this tutorial? Do you get any error msg from the php code or does it run but doesn't send the emails?

Comment: Well I 'think' it runs but it doesn't give any indication of doing so, I followed your tutorial but it still is not working.

Comment: You are using Windows 8 ?

Answer (score 0):

using the php mail driver aint good for several reasons ,

u can instead try something call phpmailer http://phpmailer.worxware.com which will teach u a better way of doing things like that without frustration ,also incase later u wanted to use a php framework u will feel right at home because they will mostly be using the same syntax.

note that sending mails at first may take some time ,maybe even hours b4 u get anything ,for that u can use something like a fakesmtp https://nilhcem.github.io/FakeSMTP/ to catch the emails.